# How to Access H2 Database Created by Micronaut Application in Browser

Tags: h2, micronaut

During development of a Micronaut application I want to be able to check the H2 database. Normally when I've worked with H2 in Grails I am able to access a client through my browser but for Micronaut I can't seem to find a URL bound to the H2 client. I can see my database URL is `jdbc:h2:mem:default`.

Is there a way to view the H2 databse through my web browser when it is created in a basic Micronaut application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature has not been implemented. Please file an issue if you would like it to be in the future